# Vue page calls JS method's this object undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, undefined

It will realize the effect of water flow pipeline, but when calling custom JS, it will report JS this undefined. Here is the code and error message. Please solve it. Thank you
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: Where do you set `self.lines` ? Also you should use `this` and arrow functions. I am fairly sure the issue is because of a confusion amongst all the `self` variables / arguments.

Comment: Curiously, I can't add code. In the third picture, line 105 reports an error. In this case, self is this

Comment: The error is telling you that `self.lines` is undefined and therefore doesn't have a property `length`. What is `self`, how is it instantiated in the contructor?